# Attach/detach in R behaving very strangely

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to subset a dataframe by applying two conditions to it. When I attach the dataframe, apply the first condition, detach the dataframe, attach it again, apply the second condition, and detach again, I get the expected result, a dataframe with 9 observations.

Of course, you wouldn't normally detach/attach before applying the second condition. So I attach, apply the two conditions after one another, and then detach. But the result is different now: It's a dataframe with 24 observations. All but 5 of these observations consist exclusively of NA-values.

I know there's lots of advice against using attach, and I understand the point that it's dangerous, because it's easy to loose track of an attach statement still being active. My point here is a different one; I see a behaviour in attach that I just can't understand. I'm using R Studio 0.99.465 with 64-bit-R 3.2.1.

So here's the code, first the version that is clumsy, but produces the correct result (df with 9 observations, all non-NA):

```
 df <- expand.grid(early_vvl=c(0,1), inter_churn=c(0,1), inter_new_contract=c(0,1), late_vvl=c(0,1), late_no_reaction=c(0,1))
  attach(df)
  df <- df[(1-early_vvl) >= inter_churn + inter_new_contract + late_vvl,]
  detach(df)
  attach(df)
  df <- df[early_vvl <= late_no_reaction,]
  detach(df)
```

Now the one that produces the dataframe with 24 observations, most of which consist only of NA values:

```
df <- expand.grid(early_vvl=c(0,1), inter_churn=c(0,1), inter_new_contract=c(0,1), late_vvl=c(0,1), late_no_reaction=c(0,1))
attach(df)
df <- df[(1-early_vvl) >= inter_churn + inter_new_contract + late_vvl,]
df <- df[early_vvl <= late_no_reaction,]
detach(df)
```

I'm puzzled. Does anybody understand why the second version produces a different result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at what happens here:

```
attach(df)
df <- df[(1-early_vvl) >= inter_churn + inter_new_contract + late_vvl,]
length(early_vvl <= late_no_reaction)
## [1] 32
df <- df[early_vvl <= late_no_reaction,]
detach(df)
```

So your logical vector `early_vvl <= late_no_reaction` still uses the original `df`, the one that you attached. When you subset the `data.frame` the second time, the logical is longer than the `data.frame` has rows and it behaves like this:

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:5, y = letters[1:5])
df[rep(c(TRUE, FALSE), 5), ]
##       x    y
## 1     1    a
## 3     3    c
## 5     5    e
## NA   NA <NA>
## NA.1 NA <NA>
```

You could just use `&` to avoid the problem:

```
df <- expand.grid(early_vvl=c(0,1), inter_churn=c(0,1), inter_new_contract=c(0,1), late_vvl=c(0,1), late_no_reaction=c(0,1))
attach(df)
df <- df[(1-early_vvl) >= inter_churn + inter_new_contract + late_vvl & early_vvl <= late_no_reaction,]
detach(df)
```

Comment: ...thus demonstrating why attach should be avoided.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the lighting-fast, clear and comprehensive answer! This was the last time I was using attach...