# R stats::aggregate()'s "object not found" error: Two similar tests with different results?

Tags: r, statistics

Here are two sample codes, both intended to exhibit/test aggregate() from R's stats package. This first one I have taken from [here](https://www.statmethods.net/management/aggregate.html):

```
attach(mtcars)
aggdata <-aggregate(mtcars, by=list(cyl,vs), 
FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE)
print(aggdata)
```

This returns what it's supposed to:

```
Group.1 Group.2      mpg cyl   disp       hp     drat       wt     qsec vs        am     gear     carb
1       4       0 26.00000   4 120.30  91.0000 4.430000 2.140000 16.70000  0 1.0000000 5.000000 2.000000
2       6       0 20.56667   6 155.00 131.6667 3.806667 2.755000 16.32667  0 1.0000000 4.333333 4.666667
3       8       0 15.10000   8 353.10 209.2143 3.229286 3.999214 16.77214  0 0.1428571 3.285714 3.500000
4       4       1 26.73000   4 103.62  81.8000 4.035000 2.300300 19.38100  1 0.7000000 4.000000 1.500000
5       6       1 19.12500   6 204.55 115.2500 3.420000 3.388750 19.21500  1 0.0000000 3.500000 2.500000
```

Now let's try a short code I wrote to test aggregate():

```
a = data.frame('t'=c(6,7),'u'=c(8,9),'house' = c(1,2))
b = data.frame('t'=c(1,2),'u'=c(3,4),'house' = c(2,3))
c = rbind(a,b)
aggregate(c,by=list(house),FUN=mean,na.rm=TRUE)
```

I am completely lost. I can't find any reason why the test case I have is different from the first sample case, yet it returns a different result:

```
Error in aggregate.data.frame(c, by = list(house), FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE) : 
 object 'house' not found
```

What might the issue be here? How do the first and second test cases differ? What am I missing?

Comment: Try this: `aggregate(c ,by=list(c$house),FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE)
` Note: You have "tell" `aggregate` function where to find `house` column.

Comment: The 'attach' is missing in the second case, so you cannot use 'house' but 'c$house'.

Comment: @Miha and @Nicolas2 Thanks, that indeed works and solves the issue. Now I have a more specific question: Why is it that `mtcars`'s columns are findable by `aggregate()`, while my data frame `c`'s aren't?

Comment: See the documentation for 'attach'.

Comment: `library("fortunes"); fortune(379)` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32965552/attach-detach-in-r-behaving-very-strangely

Comment: Thanks everyone. I had assumed that `attach()` simply loads in data from R's sample datasets. I looked up the doc for the function and that answered this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should attach your dataset before running that code:

```
attach(c)
aggregate(c,by=list(house),FUN=mean,na.rm=TRUE)
```

You can also define the variable house in the aggregate function as follows:

```
aggregate(c,by=list(c$house),FUN=mean,na.rm=TRUE)
```

Hope this helps.